# Calendar 'date(byAdding:to:options:)' is unavailable after Swift 4 update

Tags: swift

How do I use the new way? What is this `wrappingComponents`if the previous call was passing Options(0)?

> 'date(byAdding:to:options:)' is unavailable: use
>   date(byAdding:to:wrappingComponents:) instead

wrappingComponents: If true, the component should be incremented and wrap around to zero/one on overflow, and should not cause higher components to be incremented. The default value is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `NSCalendar date(byAdding:to:options:)` states the following for the `options` parameter:

> If you specify no options, overflow in a unit carries into the higher units (as in typical addition)

The documentation for `Calendar date(byAdding:to:wrappingComponents:)` states the following for the `wrappingComponents` parameter:

> If true, the component should be incremented and wrap around to zero/one on overflow, and should not cause higher components to be incremented.

This implies that `false` will cause higher components to be incremented.

So it would seem that for the `Calendar date(byAdding:to:wrappingComponents:)` you would want to pass `false` to be the same as the old function with no options.

Comment: Thank you. I came to the same conclusion, but your answer helps me validate my assumptions. Swift keeps changing and it's becoming really hard to track all the changes.